# Power generator powered exclusively by gravity is possible?

Tags: gravity, energy

According to [this site](http://rarenergia.com.br/), it seems so.

Power generator powered exclusively by gravity:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Would be good if you can translate the essentials of the site and put it here

Comment: Scroll down, on the site, there is the text in English.

Comment: People should not be down voting this question. It's absolutely fine to ask this.

Answer (score 7):

**No.** Newtonian gravity is a [conservative vector field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_vector_field) (or [conservative force](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_force)) which mean that energy that you extract from the field has to be put in first. This is technically stated as **the work done around any closed looped is equal to zero**. For example, you raise your pet cat up 1 meter (you do work against gravity) you let go and gravity does the same amount of work on your cat. Any work done by a mechanical machine must obey the same principle.

In summary, no, a generator cannot be powered by gravity because you simply cannot extract net work from the field.

However, [hydroelectricity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydroelectricity) is an example of using gravity to do work, but in this instance to water was already at the higher potential.